# Slow performance when watching YouTube videos – related to ReadyBoost?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, memory, performance, readyboost

I got 2GB of RAM and a ReadyBoost SD card that's a 16bg SDHC card. Maximum ReadyBoost is 4GB, and I never remove it.

My virtual memory is now 4GB and it's staying at that – is that good? When I'm on YouTube, the video sound is excellent the actual video itself becomes slow after watching one video, and sometimes even instantly.

What could be the cause of this? Could ReadyBoost be involved?

```
Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz, 3000 Mhz, 1 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 2.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   1.87 GB
Available Physical Memory   871 MB
Total Virtual Memory    3.98 GB
Available Virtual Memory    2.38 GB
Page File Space 2.16 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
```

Comment: First, why this question was downvoted? As to @nick, do experience stuttering or simply slowness in video usually looking like slowness in video games that you play with slow video card?

Answer (score 2):

It's very, very unlikely that your video issues have anything to do with ReadyBoost. But you can find out very easily, disable ReadyBoost and see if they go away.

Comment: When in doubt, run a test.  Actually, run a test **regardless** since as humans, we suck at performance evaluations.